# iphone (or ipad mini) as a helmet mounted display

Tags: iphone, ipad, case

I like to watch educational videos from coursera on my iphone or ipad mini while I walk.

I was thinking of making a helmet mounted mount where I could essentially do without holding the ipad in my hand - perhaps using a bicycle helmet as a starting point.

Question: Do you know of something like this that already exists?

Note: The TregoBag will not fit my requirements I think.

Thanks.